# python: check if I am currently at specific directory with os.walk()

Tags: python, hierarchical-data, os.walk

I want to go through a hirarchy-tree and check if I am at a specific directory (see picture). If this is true, I want to append this path (including the filenames in this path) to an array. I got stuck at the part where I want to check the current directory. Here is my code so far:

```
PATH = "../../data/"
paths = []

for path, dir, filenames in os.walk(PATH):
    if dir == "root/dir2/1":
        for filename in filenames:
            paths.append(os.path.join(path, filename))
        break
```

[Hierarchy-tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I0wx.jpg)

Comment: why loop over number folders and check for particular folder? Just try to access the folder - it will succeed or fail if the folder does not exist. Maybe I misunderstand your goal?

Comment: Unrelated: [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) is a built-in Python keyword and should not be used as a variable name.

Comment: The value you're calling `dir` is a *list of subdirectory names* - `dirnames` might be a better name for it.  It will never be equal to any string.  `path` is what tells you what directory is currently being walked, but I'm pretty sure it will never be equal to your string (it will be whatever path you passed to `os.walk()`, with additional directories added onto the end).  Note that if you're only interested in files in a single directory, you should just use `os.listdir()` on that directory; `os.walk()` is inappropriate.

Comment: How about `glob.glob('**/1', recursive=True)`?

Comment: @buran the thing is, that each folder exists. I just want to find a specific folder.

Comment: @jasonharper thx for the information. I checked the docs of os.listdir() but I think it is not the thing what I want because listdir() lists all folders and files in a specific directory. But the important thing is that I first have to find the directory which I am looking for. I don't know how listdir() should help me here.

Comment: @KlausD. thanks for that. This was the thing what I was looking for.